# Pass array in Mysql query with nodejs

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js

I have a simple query that I want to pass an array inside which has 5 items. I am using the `mysql` module so I know it can be done but am not doing the synatx right and therefore getting a syntax error.

Below is the query:

```
`UPDATE table1 SET table1.col=0 WHERE (table1.col2) IN = (?) AND table1.id=(SELECT ...);`,[arr]

//arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I have tried:

```
`UPDATE table1 SET table1.col=0 WHERE (table1.col2) IN = (?,?,?,?,?) AND table1.id=(SELECT ...);`,[arr]`
```

but I still get a syntax error.

Comment: *What* syntax error? Please include the full text of the error in your question, or edit to add it.

Comment: Okay am an idiot, I had forgotten the `AND` in the WHERE clause (I know its included here) and that was the error, I just saw it and thought it was for the array but now that you made me saw it I realised it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the `IN()` predicate does not use `=`.

```
WHERE (table1.col2) IN = (?,?,?,?,?)
```

should be

```
WHERE table1.col2 IN (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Tip: you can (and should) check syntax yourself in the documentation, so you can get answers more easily than posting to Stack Overflow.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: I'll accept the answer since indeed it does not use, I had removed it in my code but forgotten here, also thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 9):

Adding on to Bill Karwin's answer, you can also pass an array to the MySQL query against the '?' placeholder in the same way

```
WHERE table1.col2 IN (?)
//arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Passing arr along with the query will convert it to the required SQL string. The mysql module uses the 'SqlString.arrayToList' function from 'sqlstring' module internally for the transformation:
https://github.com/mysqljs/sqlstring/blob/8f193cae10a2208010102fd50f0b61e869e14dcb/lib/SqlString.js#L60

Answer (score 6):

In my case, array inside of array is needed to get this working. Just array variable as parameter passed only first number to sql.

Here is an example: (Notice ids inside of array as the second parameter)

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (?)";
var ids = [1,2,3];

pool.query(sql, [ids], function (err, result, fields) {

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```