# right syntax for IN (sql nodejs)

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Hi everyone so I try to use the IN sql command in sql node js plugin. I try a lot of syntax but all doesn't work. Can you help me ?

Thanks

Code :

```
var arr = log1.map( function(el) { return el.token; });

con.query( 'SELECT Nomfamille,prenomutilisateur FROM utilisateurs WHERE idpublic  IN = ' + arr.join() + '',  function (error, results, fields) {
```

another syntax :

```
 con.query( 'SELECT Nomfamille,prenomutilisateur FROM utilisateurs WHERE idpublic  IN = (' + arr.join() + ')',  function (error, results, fields) {
```

and :

```
con.query( 'SELECT Nomfamille,prenomutilisateur FROM utilisateurs WHERE idpublic  IN =  ?  ', [arr.join()] function (error, results, fields) {
```

the error :

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 23246,18200' at line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass array in Mysql query with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535318/pass-array-in-mysql-query-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you don't need  `=`  but just `IN` eg:

```
 con.query( 'SELECT Nomfamille,prenomutilisateur 
         FROM utilisateurs 
         WHERE idpublic  IN  (' + arr.join() + ')',  function (error, results, fields) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace following:

```
IN =  ?
```

with:

```
IN (?)
```