# MySQL IN returning only the results of the first item in the array

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT prefix FROM username_prefix_pool LEFT JOIN user_creds ON user_creds.prefix_id = username_prefix_pool.id WHERE user_creds.id IN (?);
```

With the following parameter:

```
[ 96, 62, 95, 92, 91 ]
```

I've tested this query via MySQL workbench, and it does return results, five of them.

However, in my code (node.js), it only ever returns the result of the first item in the list.

```
.then((mapListResults) => {
    // ^^ results from another query
    mapList = mapListResults; // <--- Stores the result
    for (let i = 0; i < mapList.length; i++) {
        authorIds.push(mapList[i].author_id.toString());
    }

    console.log('Author IDs');
    console.log(authorIds); // this is the [ 96, 62, 95, 92, 91 ] 

    let searchsql = `SELECT prefix FROM username_prefix_pool LEFT JOIN user_creds ON user_creds.prefix_id = username_prefix_pool.id WHERE user_creds.id IN (?)`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(searchsql, authorIds, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log(rows);
                resolve(rows);
            }
        });
    });

})
```

I have tried turning the array into an array of strings, but to no avail.  I have also tried removing the parenthesis on the SQL statement (that resulted in a query error, so I put it back).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This is because you are giving a list in authorIds. You should give a string with all the elements in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder it is just taking the first element of your list, because it thinks there are more placeholders for the rest of elements. You should provide  just a string.

You should change your code, so you convert your list to string with something like this:

```
console.log('Author IDs');
console.log(authorIds); // this is the [ 96, 62, 95, 92, 91 ] 
authorIds=authorIds.join(); // add this line in your code
console.log(authorIds); // you will get a string with 96,62,95,92,91
let searchsql = `SELECT prefix FROM username_prefix_pool LEFT JOIN user_creds ON user_creds.prefix_id = username_prefix_pool.id WHERE user_creds.id IN (?)`;
```

Comment: Strange, this says that I can pass an array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535318/pass-array-in-mysql-query-with-nodejs

In any case, unfortunately it didn't work. I'm still only getting details of ID 96.

Comment: Yes, but to use a list, you should give a placeholder for each element of the list like this: **searchsql = "SELECT prefix FROM username_prefix_pool LEFT JOIN user_creds ON user_creds.prefix_id = username_prefix_pool.id WHERE user_creds.id IN (?,?,?,?,?)";**

Comment: I dunno why your initial code didn't work (it seemed logical), but that one just did! Thanks