# Node.js mysql2 WHERE id in (?), [ids] returns array with one result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysql2

I have a static method `getResults(insertIds)` inside a class:

```js
static async getResults(insertIds) {
  const [result] = await Driver.pool.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id in (?)",
    [insertIds]
  );
  return result;
}
```

`Driver.pool` returns a pool instance that was created with `mysql.createPool`. I'm using [mysql2 library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) for Node.

When I log the result of `MyClass.getResults([6, 8, 10, 12].join(','))`, I get an array with a single result (If I don't join the ids with a comma, I get 0 rows). If I run the same query using Query window in the MySQL Workbench, I get all 4 rows back:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id in (6, 8, 10, 12);
```

What am I doing wrong? Using Windows.

Edit: [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535318/pass-array-in-mysql-query-with-nodejs) does not answer my question. My issue is different, I pass the array like in the provided link, but it returns only a single element.

Comment: you need as many ? as ids if i'm not mistaking

Comment: I could do that way, but it would be more convenient to use `in` operator, especially if the query like that works in general. I'd have to count the length of an array and insert `?`s in the query string. Would that be acceptable? I know it is generally considered a bad practice to insert string in the queries directly.

Comment: Depends on the library. But I think with mysql2 its the follwoing: If you want to replace the `?` for the in, you have to pass your parameters as `[[insertIds]]`. Because if you only pass a flat array, each value in the array replaces one `?`. But if one of values in the parameter array is an array itself, the library will expand it accordingly, so that `?` will be replaced by the expanded array

Comment: i think the problem in `[6, 8, 10, 12].join(',')`, because the numbers were converted to  be string as well.

Comment: When I pass `[[insertIds]]` to the execute method, it returns an empty array.

Comment: `\`${Array([6, 8, 10, 12].length).fill("?")}\` `

Comment: Then it is the `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql` where this should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass array in Mysql query with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535318/pass-array-in-mysql-query-with-nodejs)

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM test WHERE id in (' + insertIds.map(() => '?').join(',') + ')',
      insertIds`   where insertIds is an array

Comment: Whenever I try to pass dynamic number of `?`s, I get `Malformed communication packet` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. I should have used `pool.query` instead of `pool.execute`. You can read full explanation in this [Mysql2 Github issue](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/476)

> This is the way prepared statements work, I think we should document that better

> .execute() under the hood is doing prepare + execute commands